# Wrong value output

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make the program give me the lowest and the highest value in the array.

Here's my code :

```
     int z=10;
     int a[z]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

   for (int x=1;x<=10;x++) {
   cout << "How many pancakes were eaten by P"<<x<<endl;
   cin >> a[x];}
int maxPancakes = a[0];
int glutton;
int minPancakes = a[0];
int mN;

for (int x = 0; x <= z; x++) {

    if (a[x] >= maxPancakes) {

        maxPancakes = a[x];
        glutton = x;
    }

    else if (a[x] <= minPancakes) {

        minPancakes = a[x];
        mN = x;

    }
}
```

**The code for the highest value is working, but the code for the lowest value keeps on giving me wrong values (random big numbers)**

i'd appreciate any help,thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: What is the definition of `a` and `z`?

Comment: You need to initialize your variables, otherwise they will start out with whatever value was left in that location in memory.  `glutton = 0`, `mN = std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.  Also, what is the initial value of `a[0]`?

Comment: @0x5453 First, `glutton` and `mN` store indices, not values. Second, since the current min and max are equal to the first element, and he uses `<=` and `>=` to compare, both `glutton` and `mN` will be set to `0` on the first iteration, every time.

Comment: Check out the [documentation page for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/3017/arrays#t=20170601190241067949). You're probably missing an initialization for a[] which is resulting in your random number, and I don't know about z either.

Comment: @DrZoo It's probably just a partial code sample. There's no way "the code for the highest value is working" if `a` and `z` were never initialised.

Comment: z = arraySize which is 10 in this case.
a = arrayName.

Comment: Suggestion: Invest time in learning to use the debugging software that came with your development environment. It is possibly the best software development productivity tool you will ever encounter and the time you spend on learning to use it will pay immediate dividends.

Comment: @Dukeling I had a small typeo. I meant that is probably wasn't initialized to something. Thanks for pointing that out for me

Comment: It is a partial code sample, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Use the debugger to take a close look at how many iterations `x <= z`  allows.

Comment: I added the other part of the code, sorry again, i never used a debugger cause i never thought i had one, just started yesterday :/, sorry.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Whoops, good point, that's what I get for only skimming over the question.

Comment: No worries.  Now that you know the debugger is there, use it. After a few hours of playing with the debugger, it will make your programming life hundreds of times  easier. You will be able to watch the program as it executes, line by line if you have to, and see what the program did and all the information it had at it's disposal to make those decisions.

Comment: Indices for an array start by 0 not 1. You have 10 elements in your array, traverse it by 0 to 9...not 1 to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use standard library. It will make your life easier and code safer (and most of the time also faster).

For the array since C++11 you can use `std::array`, if you are working with the older C++ standard you can use `std::vector`.

Please note that in your code you are creating array with 10 elements but in the second loop you are iterating 11 times. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and... 10.

The value of the `a[10]` is undefined, it can be anything (random value).

In the first `for` loop you are setting the values for `a[1]` (second element), `a[2]` (third element), ... , `a[10]` (eleventh element, bad!).

Fix this loops and check what will happen. You can also start "debugging" with something easier than gdb (which is awesome btw. and you should learn it). You can simply print the values (read about `std::cout`) in every iteration to see when exactly this "random big numbers" are found.

**EDIT**

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    cout << "How many pancakes were eaten by P" << x << endl;
    cin >> a[x];
}

int maxPancakes = a[0];
int glutton;
int minPancakes = a[0];
int mN;

for (int x = 0; x < z; x++)
{

    if (a[x] > maxPancakes)
    {

        maxPancakes = a[x];
        glutton = x;
    }
    else if (a[x] < minPancakes)
    {

        minPancakes = a[x];
        mN = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: So i'm supposed to put in the for loop (x=0,x<10,x++), because i did try that and unfortunately it's still giving me random numbers.

Comment: @MarioSOUPER I edited my answer and added sample code. I tried to not change your code but to only fix the mistakes. Please pay attention to the statements in `if` and `for`.